# Excel Macro - Remove rows and then relabel a cell value

Tags: vba, excel

What I'm trying to do is remove any rows where a cell value in a specific column matches what is defined to remove.  After that is done re-sequence the value in another column by group.

Using the example below:
I want to look at column B and remove any rows that have a value of A or C.  Then I want to basically renumber after the dot (.) in column A to reset itself.

**Before Macro Code Fig. 1**

[image: Before macro code]

**After value A and C are removed Fig. 2**

[image]

**Final list after column A is renumbered Fig. 3**
[image: After macro code]

I figured out how to remove the rows using this code, but stuck on what to do next:

```
Sub DeleteRowBasedOnCriteriga()
Dim RowToTest As Long

For RowToTest = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1

    With Cells(RowToTest, 2)
        If .Value = "A" Or .Value = "C" _
        Then _
        Rows(RowToTest).EntireRow.Delete
    End With

Next RowToTest

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a pattern to your renumbering scheme?

Comment: @BobtimusPrime - I believe it just looks at the text left of `\\`, and numbers from 0 when it's the same, restarting at a new value.

Comment: @BruceWayne Thanks. Alternatively it looks like it could be when the pattern in column B restarts, but I'm guessing Column A will be what they're going off of.

Comment: It is column A..group would be CAT and DOG in this example.  The number scheme is just starts at 0 and goes until the group ends.

Comment: As a note - Criteria is spelled incorrectly in your sub's title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be easier to do looping from the top down (using step 1 instead of step -1). I've tried to stay true to your original coding and made this:

```
Sub DeleteRowBasedOnCriteriga()
Dim RowToTest As Long
Dim startRow As Long
Dim i As Integer

startRow = 2

'Clear the rows that have "A" or "C" in column B
For RowToTest =  Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row to startRow To Step -1

    With Cells(RowToTest, 2)
       If .Value = "A" Or .Value = "C" _
        Then _
        Rows(RowToTest).EntireRow.Delete
    End With

Next RowToTest

'If the left 3 characters of the cell above it are the same,_
'then increment the renumbering scheme
For RowToTest = startRow To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If Left(Cells(RowToTest, 1).Value, InStr(1, Cells(RowToTest, 1), "\")) = Left(Cells(RowToTest, 1).Offset(-1, 0).Value, InStr(1, Cells(RowToTest, 1), "\")) Then
        i = i + 1
        Cells(RowToTest, 1).Value = Left(Cells(RowToTest, 1).Value, InStr(1, Cells(RowToTest, 1), ".")) & i
    Else
        i = 0
        Cells(RowToTest, 1).Value = Left(Cells(RowToTest, 1).Value, InStr(1, Cells(RowToTest, 1), ".")) & i
    End If
Next RowToTest

End Sub
```

EDIT: I've updated it to compare all of the string before the backslash and compare using that.
EDIT++: It has been brought to my attention that when deleting rows it is better to work from the bottom up (step -1) to ensure every row is accounted for. I've re-implemented the original steps in the first code.

Comment: D'oh! I forgot about using `Instr()`. Much nicer than what I was doing originally, which was a mix of `left()`, and `mid()` to parse that out. Good thinking.

Comment: @jsotola If that's the case, the individual loops can have separate steps. See Edit++

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly, this isn't probably the most efficient, but it should work.

```
Sub DeleteRowBasedOnCriteriga()
Dim RowToTest As Long, i As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For RowToTest = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    With Cells(RowToTest, 2)
        If .Value = "A" Or .Value = "C" Then Rows(RowToTest).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
Next RowToTest

Dim totalRows As Long
totalRows = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Dim curCelTxt As String, aboveCelTxt As String
For i = totalRows To i Step -1
    If i = 1 Then Exit For
    curCelTxt = Left(Cells(i, 1), WorksheetFunction.Search("\", Cells(i, 1)))
    aboveCelTxt = Left(Cells(i - 1, 1), WorksheetFunction.Search("\", Cells(i - 1, 1)))
    If curCelTxt = aboveCelTxt Then
        Cells(i, 1).Value = ""
    Else
        Cells(i, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Cells(i, 1), Right(Cells(i, 1), Len(Cells(i, 1)) - WorksheetFunction.Search(".", Cells(i, 1))), "0")
    End If
Next i

Dim rng As Range, cel As Range
Dim tempLastRow As Long
Set rng = Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)
For Each cel In rng
    If cel.Offset(1, 0).Value = "" Then
        tempLastRow = cel.End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 0).Row
        If tempLastRow = Rows.Count - 1 Then
            tempLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
            cel.AutoFill Destination:=Range(cel, Cells(tempLastRow, 1))
            Exit For
        Else
            cel.AutoFill Destination:=Range(cel, Cells(tempLastRow, 1))
        End If
    End If
Next cel
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Mainly, I discovered that you can use `AutoFill` to fix the last number in the string. Meaning if you `AutoFill` this text, `CAT\Definitions.0` down, you get the number updating as you drag/fill.